# Multiple Chromecast senders on a single web page

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

We discovered that the Chromecast plugin cannot register two cast buttons when there are more than one player embedded with Chromecast plugin available.

The visible console error is: 
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'registerElement' on 'Document': Registration failed for type 'google-cast-button'. A type with that name is already registered.

It also appears that the cast framework is changing the css property of the second button to display:none once there is another player using it.

Test page representing the error: https://jsbin.com/repivowuge/edit?html,js,output

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h2>Chromecast 'google-cast-button' error, toggle browser console to see</h2>
  <h3>Player 1</h3>
<script src="https://cdnapisec.kaltura.com/p/1673641/sp/167364100/embedIframeJs/uiconf_id/41860021/partner_id/1673641"></script>
<div id="kaltura_player_1519307906" style="width: 560px; height: 395px;"></div>
<script>
kWidget.embed({
  "targetId": "kaltura_player_1519307906",
  "wid": "_1673641",
  "uiconf_id": 41860021,
  "flashvars": {
    "streamerType": "auto",
    "chromecast.plugin": true
  },
  "cache_st": 1519307906,
  "entry_id": "1_4bc211jv"
});
</script>
    <h3>Player 2</h3>
<div id="kaltura_player_1519307903" style="width: 560px; height: 395px;"></div>
<script>
kWidget.embed({
  "targetId": "kaltura_player_1519307903",
  "wid": "_1673641",
  "uiconf_id": 41860021,
  "flashvars": {
    "streamerType": "auto",
    "chromecast.plugin": true
  },
  "cache_st": 1519307906,
  "entry_id": "1_4bc211jv"
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Taken [from here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/74469007), Google official answer on the matter

> Thanks for reporting the issue. It looks like you are loading the
>   sender twice in the page. Usually, you can have multiple buttons in
>   the page however the "google-cast-button" registration would be one.
>   From the error message, it indicates that the type is being registered
>   twice.
>
> We don't support registering "google-cast-button" twice.

So if you use `<button is="google-cast-button"></button>` as [recommended here](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/chrome_sender_integrate#cast_button) for CAF sender, then you can only have one of those. The second one would need to be a custom button.